# W3 Total Cache and IIS7 not doing much

Tags: plugins, cache, plugin-w3-total-cache

I have my WordPress blog up and running on an IIS7 server and I installed W3 Total Cache. At some point prior to WordPress 3.2 upgrade, everything seemed to be working, but since then (and quite possibly, some plugin installations) all it does is add a single `<meta>` tag after the `<head>` tag and its footer saying "Performance Optimization by...". It doesn't cache anything, it doesn't change browser cache settings in the response header. It doesn't work.

I can't work out what is going on, so I'm hoping someone here recognises this issue and can help. I have WordPress 3.2.1 and W3 Total Cache 0.9.2.3. The other active plug-ins I have are:

- Akismet 2.5.3
- FeedBurner FeedSmith Extend 1.0.0
- Google Analytics for WordPress 1.1.3
- Recommended Reading: Google Reader Shared 4.0.4
- Share and Follow 1.54.1
- SyntaxHighlighter Evolved 3.1.3
- TinyMCE Valid Elements 0.3
- Tweet Blender 3.3.14
- Twitter Facebook Social Share 2.0.0

I have turned on the debugging feature but nothing gets appended to the page.

I will continue to investigate but if anyone can see where my issue lies, please answer accordingly. Why won't W3 Total Cache, cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more investigation last night, I discovered the problem lay in a malformed PHP file within my very simple child theme.

The child theme was just a stylesheet and a PHP file, so it wasn't difficult to determine where the problem lay within the theme. A quick look at the PHP showed that it included just  `<?php?>`. I deleted the file and now everything is working again.